# Bootstrap (HTML) class suggestions in VS Code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to transition from Visual Studion Pro 2013 to Visual Studio Code. It seems Code doesn't grok HTML class suggestions the way VS 2013 does. Am I missing a config option or something? I searched for bootstrap in the options but found nothing.

[image]

```
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ=="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <span class=""
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: AFAIK the HTML plugin needs some improvements to that direction.

Comment: @Wosi yep. I looked at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html and there's nothing to say that CSS classes are supported. I guess I just thought they would be.

Comment: I assume the VS support helpline couldn't help? That would be the first place to check for support.

Comment: @Paulie_D VS Code has a helpline? The docs (cited in my other comment) don't say either way how to configure.

Comment: I'd assume so...there's no contact link?

Comment: To the downvoters who didn't comment: VS Code's web page states to ask on Stackoverflow: https://code.visualstudio.com/Home/Connect

Answer (score 1):

*In a nutshell:*
1. Install [HTML CSS Support Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css) in vscode. i.e:  `ext install vscode-html-css`
2. Add an `resource.json` file inside your `.vscode` or project root folder, you can configure paths to your used style sheets.
3.Add the following code to the `resource.json` file.

```
{
  "css": {
    "style": [

      "replace_with_path_to_your_css_bootstrap_file" //i.e bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css
    ]
  }
}
```

save &
done!!
**Credits:** [dwonisch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213941/how-to-add-intellisense-to-visual-studio-code-for-bootstrap#answer-40705076)