# how to add Intellisense to Visual Studio Code for bootstrap

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to have intellisense for bootstrap specifically but even for the css styles I write in my project.  I've got references in a project.json and a bower.json but they do not seem to be making the references available.

Answer (score 176):

You can install [HTML CSS Support Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css).

`ext install vscode-html-css`

This will add Intellisense in your HTML files:

[image: Bootstrap Intellisense]

You don't need to configure anything for local files, just close and reopen vscode after installing. For remote css files, you can add the following

```
"css.styleSheets": [
  "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

in the `settings.json`

Comment: is it possible to see icons in intellisense? for example for font awesome

Comment: It really needs an extension for VSC to provide css intellisense?! And how in hell would you know that you need that and css intellisense isn't just a configuration setting? And how would you then know which extension to use? Seems to be totally obscure and unusable if you are not friends with the VSC developers. Same problem seems to apply to about everything in the realm of software development these days.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore probably after VScode update

Comment: Can confirm it still works as of writing this comment.

Comment: it doesn't work. Try btn-white with bootstrap css.

Comment: need to change "css.remoteStyleSheets" to >> "css.styleSheets" and it will work

Comment: Probably adding first the setting (with "css.styleSheets") and then installing the extension worked for me

Comment: if using Django dont forget to tell the extension to load the intellisense in django-html files "css.enabledLanguages": [
        "html",
        "django-html"
    ]

Comment: Anyone tried with React/TypeScript React?

Comment: Installed and restarted VSC. Still NOT working.  ARG!  Getting some error about a server connection being closed or some shizz. :(

Answer (score 88):

Here is the common steps *(not only for Bootstrap)* to enable **css IntelliSense** in VS Code:

**Step 1:** Go to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion

or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion

*(Installation steps are already there)*

**Step 2:** Click Install button that appear on the top of the website (screenshot below)

[image]

**Step 3:** After click, browser will show a pop-up window to access VS Code. Open it with VS Code.

**Step 4:** Click again the "install" button that appear inside the VS Code.

**Step 5:** After restarting the software, click the bottom left icon shown in the below image:

[image]

**Step 6:** Press "ctrl+[space]" inside the class quotes, you will get the complete class names from the attached stylesheets.

Comment: As always, nothing worked. I installed the extension, restarted VSC, clicked the flash, it said "CSS/SCSS classes cached". In an editor for an html file I edited a tag '<h1></h1>' to '<h1 class=""></h1>' put the cursor between the ", held Ctrl and pressed Space. And all VSC could find was "class", "h1" and "title". None of which makes sense btw. Any actual classes didn't appear. It is so enormously tiring that today nothing is ever working and 99% of your time goes to configuring things or understanding tools you will never use again.

Comment: Also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense says VSC would support Intellisense for css out of the box. But it just doesn't. How astronomically stupid is all of that?

Comment: not working all the time,if I select form vs code suggestion list 'class' then I got class="",next I put cursor inside "" and type there is no css suggest,only if I click Ctrl+space or I press space,If I delete class name and leave again "",when i first type it works

Answer (score 32):

In the latest version of VS Code the IntelliSense in comments and strings have been disabled by default.  Below are the two options to bring back "24/7 IntelliSense" functionality or customize it to your own liking.

First make sure you have installed the HTML CSS Support Extension mentioned by dwonisch above.

Control + ',' to go to settings or click File -> Preferences -> Settings.

Click workspace settings tab and enter the following JSON code:

```
{
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": false, // <- no 24x7 IntelliSense in comments
        "strings": true, // but in strings and the other parts of source files
        "other": true
    }
}
```

The other option is to hit ctrl + space within the CSS quotes to activate the intelliSense. Example:

```
<div class="(ctrl+space)"> </div>
```

Answer (score 21):

[image]

just add this 2 packeges and you are done.. !!!

Comment: Do I have to restart vs code to make it working?

Comment: It works fine without restarting VS code.

Comment: Real heroes don't wear capes. They know the extensions.

Comment: These do the same thing as far as I can tell; why do you need both?

Answer (score 9):

Just install this extension in VS Code.
[IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this feature is not currently available in VS Code. However, it has been added as a feature request for upcoming updates. You can track the issue [on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1005).

Answer (score 1):

For `React` use install this extension in VS Code

1: install [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

[image]

but this extension works on `class` property as default so update the settings to work on `className`.

2: create a `extensions.json` file in `.vscode` folder and add the below object

```
{
    "recommendations": [
        "Zignd.html-css-class-completion",
        "html-css-class-completion.JavaScriptLanguages"
    ]
}
```

- `"Zignd.html-css-class-completion"` for `class` property
- `"html-css-class-completion.JavaScriptLanguages"` for `className` property

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use extension **`IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML`** for all the HTML, CSS and Bootstrap intelligence.

I am using Latest version of `VS Code`, intelligence is working fine.

[image]

Turn `comments` on if required in `setting` by pressing `ctrl+,`

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Visual Studio Code.
2. Use **CTRL+,**  to get to the Workspace Settings
3. At your Right side window you will see something like this:
   [image]
4. Another words paste this URL

```json
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "D:\\Visual Studio\\AndreyCourse\\the-complete-web-developer-in-2018\\DocumentObjectModel"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "css.remoteStyleSheets": [
      "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ]
  }
}
```

5. Enjoy The Bootstrap Intellisense :-)

Comment: this does not work, as there is no setting called `css.remoteStyleSheets` are you using an extension that does provide such a setting?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht right: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css