# How to enable bootstrap intellisense in VS Code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intellisense, visual-studio-code

How do I enable bootstrap IntelliSense in VS Code?
I know I could use Visual Studio Community but it is so slow
but Intellisense is a big deal too.

Comment: Using this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213941/how-to-add-intellisense-to-visual-studio-code-for-bootstrap

Comment: Please refer to the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213941/how-to-add-intellisense-to-visual-studio-code-for-bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add Intellisense to Visual Studio Code for bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213941/how-to-add-intellisense-to-visual-studio-code-for-bootstrap)

Comment: I find the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40705076/2627211

Answer (score 0):

make sure bootstrap's javascript file is included, remove other html/css extensions to prevent conflict, if still doesn't work try to install bootstrap packages locally.(without CDN)