# Intellisense for bootstrap css classes in visual studio code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I want intelissense for bootstrap classes in visual studio code.
I tried every soulution given on this platform but didnt succeed.
is this feature deleted from visual studio code.

I tried following things :

[Html css support plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css)

[Intellisense for html css in visual studio code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

None of them worked.

I tried editing settings files also, wit these :

**{
    "css.fileExtensions": [
        "css",
        "scss",
        "less"
    ],

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": true,
    "strings": true
},**
```

but no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

**PS :I am using visual studio code 1.21.0**

Comment: It's as said in the official documentation. You've to use `ctrl + space` to get context specific intellisense.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_intellisense

Comment: its not populating bootstrap classes

Comment: You can try this answer here and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213941/how-to-add-intellisense-to-visual-studio-code-for-bootstrap

Comment: there is no .vscode folder or something like that

Comment: Which OS are you using? On linux you can do `cd ~/.vscode`.

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: Execute this in `Run` command: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add Intellisense to Visual Studio Code for bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213941/how-to-add-intellisense-to-visual-studio-code-for-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

[IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion) was right choice.
The extension scans through your current workspace to find all css clasess you have in the workspace.

If any of the project inside your workspace has bootstrap.css file then the extension will take all bootstrap classes.

If you don't have Bootstrap in the workspace You can install it **locally** like

```
npm i bootstrap
```

Comment: To check that it works properly try to intellisense some rare bootstrap classes You haven't use in that workspace. Like **font-weight-normal**. Unfortunatly it still `ctrl + space` needed.