# Adding Intellisense and auto complete for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I started a new job that required I use a different editor. I came from Visual Studio to now trying to use VS Code. So far my experience has been nothing short of frustrating.

Problem: Intellisense and auto complete for Bootstap does not work. In fact there's nothing that shows up at all. I also had the same issue with HTML but I found an extension that seems to have resolved that.

What I've tried: I've looked at multiple examples as how to resolve this, but nothing works. I've added the appropriate extensions with no success. HTML CSS Support, Bootstrap 4 & Font Awesome 4.

Additionally, there seems to be this settings.json file that many reference, but mine doesn't reflect what they're showing at all.

Can anyone assist in finding a solution to this? Know of a good tutorial or a location that actually works? Grateful for the help.

Frustrated VS Code newb.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of good extensions for vscode.
As for bootstrap, you can just search `bootstrap` in the extension pane.
Then you can find some really useful, high-rated, easy-to-use Bootstrap snippets extensions.
Here is an example:
[Bootstrap 4, Font awesome 4, Font Awesome 5 Free & Pro snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thekalinga.bootstrap4-vscode).

Or you can browse another questions for your answer, see:

> [How to add Intellisense to Visual Studio Code for bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213941/how-to-add-intellisense-to-visual-studio-code-for-bootstrap)

Comment: I've already installed that extension. Doesn't work. Additionally, I've followed that link you posted and tried every example listed. None of which function. If you dive into it, there's one specific answer that got approved as a solution, but no longer works for the update VS code. I can manually type in the various classes, but intellisense makes waaaaaaay easier. Sucks I can't get it working

Comment: Here's the usage of the extension I mentioned above: `To use the bootstrap snippets, open a HTML file, and start typing b4-, followed by pressing Ctrl+Space. A list of bootstrap snippets will show up`, have your tried this?(Ctrl + Space in your case should be your Trigger Suggest Keybinding which you can find in your `Preference: Open Keyboard Shortcuts` pane) If you really cannot find a auto completion language support pack, you can try this way(use snippets) as a workround.

Comment: I have. They don't show up. I've followed multiple examples all leading me down that path and they're just not there. Some random Font Awesome ones do. Ones I don't recognize, but there's not a single bootstrap snippet that shows up. Autocomplete doesn't function and neither does intellisense. On a frustrated whim I installed multiple extension hoping one would stick. Unfortunately not.