# How can I get auto complete or suggestion for classnames while writing css class in React in VS Code?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm using a css framework like Bootstrap or Prime Flex. How can I get auto complete suggestion as I type for standard classname inside my component's className props?

[Reference Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM5Sd.png)

Tried installing css extension, but no luck.

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74300374/6696239